# How to replace CTRL+C shortcut with same action plus xclip save copied selection command?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, xclip

I am trying to be able to save/log all clipboard selection copies to a clipboard_histroy.log file. I want this to be able to simply append each copied selection to the log file but at the same time still simulate ctrl+c just as your pc normally would, except in this case there is an additional xclip command going on afterwards...

I am binding the below command to the keyboard shortcut (CTRL+C) by setting it in Applications >> Settings >> Keyboard within my Manjaro Linux XFCE4 environment.

Here is what I have so far, but nothing seems to work about it.

```
xdotool key ctrl+c && xclip -selection clipboard -o >> /home/user/.logs/clipboard_history.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CopyQ 
https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/

Saved items are in `~/.config/copyq`

On KDE, the standard clipboard utility will also do what you want without any difficulty. See https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper

If you prefer to use xclip, here's one way to put the selection onto the clipboard and into a file at the same time, the following works for me.

```
xclip -sel p -o | xclip -i -sel c -f >> ~/.logs/clipboard_history.log
```

The selection is the highlighted text. It is put into the primary selection without the need for `CTRL+C`. This command puts it into the clipboard (as if you had typed `CTRL+C`) and it appends it to your history file.